# Cakephp search plugin - Search inside related model

Tags: cakephp, search, model, cakedc

Cliente hasMany Solicitud.

I am using CakeDC search plugin.

I need to search inside Solicitud where Cliente.nombre = "myValue". Is this even doable?
I paste what I have:

```
//SOLICITUD MODEL
public $actsAs = array('Search.Searchable', 'Containable');


public $filterArgs = array(
    'nombre' => array('type' => 'like', 'field' => array('Cliente.nombre')),        
);
```

I don't know if this is doable or I am fantasizing. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're fantasizing or didn't read the readme.md.

Let me shorten the example from the readme.md for you, it should become obvious:

```
class Article extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Search.Searchable');
    public $belongsTo = array('User');
    public $filterArgs = array(
        'title' => array('type' => 'like'),
        'username' => array('type' => 'like', 'field' => array(
            'User.username', 'UserInfo.first_name')),
    );
```

Notice the `Model.field` notation for the `username` filter.